# Ajax response in ArrayList using Hibernate

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, hibernate, arraylist

I am working on a project where client requirement is `...if User select one specific type from a dropdown menu so that data should display on next drop down menu like There are 3 List (pricelist, slablist, zonelist)`. if user select price list then only price list data should display on next drop down menu.
I almost reached there but I am getting `data(response)` in ArrayList Format
and I don't know next step. I mean how to put response data in a drop down menu.

Here is my code:

PriceListMapping.jsp

```
<select name="pricelisttype" id="pricelisttype" onchange="getPriceListType()">
   <option value="" >Select PriceList Type </option>
   <option value="G" >General Price List</option>
   <option value="S" >Slab Price List</option>
   <option value="Z" >Zone Price List</option>
</select>

<select name="pricinglist" id="pricinglist">
   <option value='0' >Select Price List </option>
</select>
```

```js
function getPriceListType(){
  var pricelisttype = $('#pricelisttype').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "getPriceListType",
    method: "GET",
    data: { pricelisttype: pricelisttype },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
      $('#pricinglist').html(data);
      $('#a').html(data);             
    }      
  });
}
```

PriceListMappingView.java

```
String pricelisttype = request.getParameter("pricelisttype");
if (pricelisttype.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
{
  transaction.setBiginTransaction();
  List<Object[]> l = transaction.s.createQuery("select generalPricingIds from Pricelistmaster").list();
  transaction.setCommitTransaction();
  response.getWriter().print(l);
}
```

**[Before onchange my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnmEc.png)**

**[After onchange my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec1CV.png)**

Comment: Use javascript for loop itreator or jQuery.each() and iterate over the loop.

Comment: how to do this...

Comment: It is similar to java only for(i=0;i<array.lengthli++){}

Comment: i used javascript for loop too but getting respose.

Comment: success: function (data) {
                var i;    
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                $('#a').html(data);
                $('#pricinglist').html(data);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, I would recommend that you avoid trying to filter the price list inside your web page using Javascript and instead influence this inside your controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/pricelists")
public @ResponseBody getPriceLists(@RequestParam("type") String type) {
  if ( "G".equals( type ) ) {
    // ignore this type, return an empty list perhaps??
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
  else {
    // query the database doing something like
    // SELECT * FROM PriceListTable WHERE PriceListType = :priceListType
    return priceLists.getPriceListsByType( type );
  }
}
```

In the page, all you have to be concerned with is taking the json array and appending that to your `<select/>` html tag.

```
function(data) {
  var toAppend = '';
  $.each (data, function( i, o ) ) {
    toAppend = '<option value=' + o.value + '>' + o.name + '</option>';
  } );
  $( "pricingList" )
   .find("option")
   .remove()
   .end()
   .append( toAppend );
}
```

For situations where the logic to render a component might be easier to do using server-side tags rather than relying on Javascript to do that, I do advocate you consider using HTML partials.  The original page still makes an AJAX request but rather than the controller returning JSON, it would forward to a view page like your original page did.  The AJAX request expects a response of `html` rather than `json` and can simply do a dom-element replace.

Comment: //My Working Code
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        function getPriceListType(){
            var pricelisttype = $('#pricelisttype').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "getPriceListType",
                method:"GET",
                data: {pricelisttype:pricelisttype},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) { var select = $('#pricinglist');   select.find('option').remove();     $.each(data, function (index, value) {       $('<option>').val(value[0]).text(value[1]).appendTo(select);    });  }  });  } </script>

Comment: **PriceListMappingView.java**                                                                  `String pricelisttype = request.getParameter("pricelisttype");
if (pricelisttype.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
{
  transaction.setBiginTransaction();
  List<Object[]> l = transaction.s.createQuery("select generalPricingIds from Pricelistmaster").list();
  transaction.setCommitTransaction();
  String json = new Gson().toJson(l);
  response.getWriter().write(json);
}`

Comment: and add gson.xxxx.jar library...i hope i will help for other developers....